# Windows IIS wwwroot angular javascript serving up .json files not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, iis, windows-hosting

The website with index.html is located here
http://www.example.com/index.html

The is using angular/javascript and i'm trying to serve up fake data with .json files 
locally I can do this just fine. Its just very simple javascript ... If i have any CORS issues the browser will tell me in developer tools and i just enable a CORS extension in chrome.

Problem:

Go here : http://www.example.com/index.html#/devices

Reason it seems that no data is showing is the obvious message in that it cannot locate this path

http://www.example.com/api/devices.json

What am I doing wrong?

This is where devices.json is located ... under wwwroot

/example.com/wwwroot/api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS is serving 404s (not found) for various reasons, to find out what the problem for your request is, without enabled detailed errors, look at the http log files, locate the request in question and find the http sub-status:

```
192.168.1.200 GET /devices.json - 80 ... 404 3
```

the number to the right of the 404 is the sub-status, in this case the 3 means: `MIME type restriction.` IIS by default is not configured to serve status files with a `.json` extension. You have add a new MIME Type mapping in IIS on the server or site level.

Comment: You are right.  I used cpanel and added in application/json  mime type  works now   thx

Answer (score 0):

you may not be owner of http://www.example.com/

your IIS settings are wrong. Try to set ist reachable under http://localhost/ or http://127.0.0.1/

You may also modify your host file under system32 folder but it's not recommended.

Comment: 1. example.com is just a replacement for my real site name  .    But i don't believe your suggestions are even valid.

Comment: ah, ok.But there are many routing methods. And its not clear in your question which one do you use. By the way  this also seems wrong : http://www.example.com/index.html#/devices seems also wrong. it should be http://www.example.com/index.html/#devices or better http://www.example.com/#devices if your routing works properly

Comment: its  ui.router    - angular  -  this is just basis routing engine